# jQuery fadeOut animating then returning

Tags: jquery, click, fadein, fadeout

I'm attempting to make a div fadeIn when clicked, then when a div nested within this div is clicked the initial div fadesOut. It's working well up until it comes to the fadeOut part of the jQuery, it initially fades, but then returns.

Heres the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kapow!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div class = "box">
          <div class = "boxinfo">
            <div class = "exit"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.boxinfo {
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
}

.exit {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box').click(function(){
    $('.boxinfo').fadeIn();    
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.exit').click(function(){
    $('.boxinfo').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.exit').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xujyb for demo

Comment: codepen code is missing the js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking on the nested element also fires the click on the parent element, it's called propagation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').click(function(){
        $('.boxinfo').fadeIn();    
    });

    $('.exit').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.boxinfo').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly. But stops the first operation to happen. This will be a kind of gallery viewer of images, where clicking on the image brings up info etc. Sorry to be a hassle dude.

Comment: It can't stop the first event handler, that's on a different element all together ?